# How to pass parameter to custom ViewCell in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have custom `ViewCell` with two initializers with different arguments. Each initializer creates a cell differently, depending on the arguments passed. I made an `ObservableCollection` with the data that I will pass and assigned it to the `ItemsSource`. Next, you need to return the finished cell to the `ItemTemplate`, but how can I pass parameters to it?

```
    public UniversalListPage(ElementType type, List<UniversalBigClass> data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Data = new ObservableCollection<UniversalBigClass>(data);
        this.DataList.ItemsSource = this.Data;

        this.DataList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            return new UniversalCell(/*parameters from ItemSource*/);
        });
    }
```

Comment: you should use data binding to pass any relevant values

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector) to achieve this . A `DataTemplateSelector` can be used to choose a `DataTemplate` at runtime based on the value of an item’s  property. This enables multiple DataTemplates to be applied to the same type of object, to customize the appearance of particular objects.

A data template selector is implemented by creating a class that inherits from [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datatemplateselector?view=xamarin-forms). The `OnSelectTemplate` method is then overridden to return a particular `DataTemplate`, as shown in the following code example:

```
public class PersonDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate ValidTemplate { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate InvalidTemplate { get; set; }

  protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate (object item, BindableObject container)
  {
    return ((Person)item).DateOfBirth.Year >= 1980 ? ValidTemplate : InvalidTemplate;
  }
}
```

For more details, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

And there is a sample included in above document, you can check it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/templates-datatemplateselector/ .